# Show only windows and not tabs when app item is right clicked on Dock

Tags: macos, dock

Currently when you right click on an app icon in the Dock, that pulls up a menu with a list of open windows and/or Tabs

For example, When I right click on Chrome app icon then it shows the list of windows and not tabs. But when I right click on Terminal app icon then it shows the list of windows and tabs as well

Is it possible to always show the windows and not tabs when I right click on an app icon in the Dock?

Comment: That is a feature that is up to the person or company that wrote the app

Comment: Shouldn't this be configurable at OS level as well instead of relying on the app developer? The 'feature' to show the list of opened windows, tabs is something that is provided by Mac OS. Else app developers wouldn't be able to show this list

Comment: "should" and "why" are not questions we can answer here as that is up to Apple and the app developers. We, generally, only answer "how."

Comment: So you mean to say that MAC OS does not have this feature? Then thanks for confirmation

Comment: macOS clearly has the feature, but it's up to the application/the application developer to decide what is shown there.